# Can't run mvn gluonfx:link goal to create native image

Tags: javafx, gluon, graalvm-native-image

I just want to produce the native image for Windows platform from example Gluon project, but I get an error. I already install all the requirements. When run `mvn gluonfx:compile` I get no error, but when I run `mvn gluonfx:link`, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.1:link (default-cli) on project hellogluonstart: Linking failed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.1:link (default-cli) on project hellogluonstart: Linking failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Linking failed
    at com.gluonhq.NativeLinkMojo.execute (NativeLinkMojo.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

This is the log error from a log file:

```
Creating library C:\Dev\Exercise\Gluon-Lab\gluon-samples-master\HelloFX\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\HelloFX.lib and object C:\Dev\Exercise\Gluon-Lab\gluon-samples-master\HelloFX\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\HelloFX.exp
    net.lib(DefaultProxySelector.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_WinHttpOpen referenced in function Java_sun_net_spi_DefaultProxySelector_init
    net.lib(DefaultProxySelector.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_WinHttpGetProxyForUrl referenced in function Java_sun_net_spi_DefaultProxySelector_getSystemProxies
    net.lib(DefaultProxySelector.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser referenced in function Java_sun_net_spi_DefaultProxySelector_getSystemProxies
    C:\Dev\Exercise\Gluon-Lab\gluon-samples-master\HelloFX\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\HelloFX.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Comment: The exception that explains the issue is shown before the message you have posted or in a log file. Post it so we can see it, otherwise impossible to say.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you mean. Do you want me to show all the log from `[INFO] Scanning for projects...` until `[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException` ?

Comment: Just the relevant part of the log that explains the issue...

Comment: If I run without `-X`, I just get this log error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.1:link (default-cli) on project hellofx: Linking failed -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Check the logs under `target/gluonfx/log`, there’s a link related log. Post it.

Comment: I already edit the question and add log file error

Comment: Ok, that helps. Issue is known and has a fix, as explained here: https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues/348#issuecomment-868988144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank [José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda) for giving the hint to solve this error with this GitHub
[issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues/348#issuecomment-868988144).

First, we need to add the plugin repository to the pom:

```
<project>
    ...
    <pluginRepositories>
        ...
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        ...
    </pluginRepositories>
    ...
</project>
```

And then change just the `gluonfx-maven-plugin` version to `1.0.2-SNAPSHOT`. Finally, just try to build again.